# How do I create a test to determine how many times the append method has been called on a list?

Tags: python, mocking

I am trying to test that a method `bar` only appends elements to `list_of_elements` until it hits something already in its list (kind of like a cache).

a.py

```
list_of_elements = []
class Foo:
    def bar():
        global list_of_elements
        element_set = set(list_of_elements)
        new_elements = get_new_elements()
        for element in new_elements:
            if element in element_set:
                break
            list_of_elements.append(element)
        return list_of_elements
```

I want to test this by seeing how many calls to `append` occur, but I can't figure out how to properly mock `list_of_elements` to capture the calls to `append` while retaining the other functionality. So far I have:

a_test.py

```
class ATest:
    def setUp(self):
        self.foo = a.Foo()

    # Mock list_of_elements here?
    def test_bar(self):
        append = # ?????
        test_elements = [x for x in range(10)] # [0,1,2,3,...]
        self.foo.bar()
        self.assertEqual(len(test_elements), append.call_count) # 10 == 10

        test_elements = [-1] + test_elements # [-1,0,1,2,3,...]
        self.foo.bar()
        self.assertEqual(len(test_elements), append.call_count) # 11 == 11
```

Is this the correct way to go about testing what I want to test? If so, what aspect am I missing? If not, what is the better way to test this?

Comment: Don't. Test the _outcome_ - why does it matter if the list was e.g. appended to or extended?

Comment: @jonrsharpe The idea is that it takes a long time to go through the for loop, but the way the result of `get_new_elements` works you only need to iterate until you reach familiar territory, so you can shave off time by stopping early. This is a test to make sure the method works as intended.

Comment: Then is a list even the right thing to use? That's an O(n) search each time. Maybe you should be doing actual performance testing, or see whether a collaborator is interacted with in a case that should be a cache hit.

Comment: I was removing the unnecessary components of the function because it was not, in my opinion, relevant to the question at hand. I added how I actually check whether the element exists in the list (cast as a set for ~O(1) lookup time).


There isn't a collaborator, the only affected object is the list itself, unless you are suggesting I add some additional object in method `bar`?

Comment: Note there's no point using a set for O(1) lookup if you spend O(n) rebuilding it every time. In terms of collaborators I meant whatever was doing the expensive part, `get_new_elements` - the real performance question seems to be how many times _that_ gets called.